# What is secondary button / tap in Flutter gesture recogniser?

Tags: flutter, gesturedetector

Flutter's [GestureDetector](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html) has various methods for "secondary" touch gestures, but I can't figure out from the documentation what these are for. For example:

- [onSecondaryTap](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector/onSecondaryTap.html): A tap with a secondary button has occurred.
- [onSecondaryLongPress](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector/onSecondaryLongPress.html) Called when a long press gesture with a secondary button has been recognized.

What is a "secondary button"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is to handle devices that have secondary buttons (like mouses).
You can found also Ternary buttons actions.
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/62788#pullrequestreview-460331326

Answer (score 0):

Flutter apps can be published on the web as well (not just mobile apps). `onSecondaryTap` allows for the right mouse button detection.